# Angularjs slider with ng-change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have input slider like that

```
<input ng-model="value" type="text" id="mySlider1" slider ng-change="fun()"/>
```

this slider have values from 1 to 10

i need to get this value by ng-model and perform fun() with angularjs controller
when change slider.

angularjs controller

```
$scope.fun = function () {
               console.log($scope.value)
         };
```

Comment: Refer to slider directive documentation. Which one are you using?

Comment: I suggest using https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.slider/directive/mdSlider
with a $watch function on your model value to perform any functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can place a watcher on the model like this -

```
$scope.$watch("value", function(){
    // do whatever you need with the just-changed $scope.value
});
```

Comment: When you slide the slider dot, the $watch function will run for every value in between the final value, as the model changes all the way to the end, How to make it fire just on the final value?